# MySQLSyntaxErrorException when creating table

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am fairly new to MySQL with Java, but I have executed a few successful INSERT queries however cannot seem to get the CREATE TABLE query to execute without getting the `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` exception.  My code is as follows:

```
Statement stmt;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "password");
stmt = con.createStatement();
String tblSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \'dev\'.\'testTable\' (\n"
                + " \'id\' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n"
                + " \'date\' smallint(6) NOT NULL\n"
                + ") ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";
stmt.executeUpdate(tblSQL);
stmt.close();
con.close();
```

And the error is as follows:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''dev'.'testTable' (
   'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   'date' smallint(6) N' at line 1
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could spot the mistake in this query, as I've tried executing this within phpMyAdmin and it works as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\n` will make press enter effect :) make it like

```
String tblSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dev`.`testTable`"
            + "("
            + "id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,"
            + "date smallint(6) NOT NULL"
            + ")"
            + "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";
```

Comment: there is no need of comma even you can remove that, and please check syntax of query now with the version of your mysql, it seems problem with syntax now, try one thing pring string on console and try to run that in your mysql command interface find out the syntax error

Comment: I've just checked it within mysql, and there seems to be a problem with the syntax.

Comment: I've solved it, I created the same table with phpMyAdmin and just copied that code into my Java program and it works. Code is as follows:      tblSQL = "CREATE TABLE  `dev`.`testTable2` ("
                    + "`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,"
                    + "`date` INT NOT NULL ,"
                    + "`month` INT NOT NULL"
                    + ") ENGINE = MYISAM ;";

Comment: :) I was about to tell you primary key stuff,

Comment: thanks mate for shedding some light on the query itself. i thought it was a java problem.

Comment: hmmm, i've just realised that in the SQL query it doesn't accept " ' ", however it takes " ` ", when surrounding fields and db, tbl names.